# Manadev / SEO Layered Navigation Plus : how can I prevent redirect for CMS pages?

Tags: magento-1.9, third-party-module

Simple question: the extension [SEO Layered Navigation Plus](https://www.manadev.com/seo-layered-navigation-plus) is forcing a 301 redirect for all the CMS pages requested with a trailing slash.

For example:

example.com/about-us/ => 301 => example.com/about-us

I need to remove this interference and manage this on my own.

I already checked in Magento's own rewrites and there is nothing about this. Moreover:disabiling the SEO Layered Navigation Plus module does the trick (but I cannot do it as a definitive solution).

The only other place where I see references to my redirecting CMS pages is in MANAdev own SEO URL Keys:

[image]

These value are read-only and cannot be deleted.

The shop is a fully patched Magento ver. 1.9.2.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disabiling the option `Redirect To Same Page With Correct Parameter Order` in each `SEO Schema` did the trick:

```
      UPDATE
        `m_seo_schema`
      SET
        `redirect_parameter_order` = 0
```

A reindex + cache puring was needed, but this fixed my problem.